# How to populate Csv file with output of SQL in unix

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix, csv

How to populate Csv file with output of SQL queries in unix

what i have done is

```
#! /bin/ksh

echo ",A,B,C\n D\n E">abc.csv

sqlplus -s scott/tiger@host<< EOF >> abc.csv

SET COLSEP ","

SET HEADING OFF

select   count(a1)  from tab1 where condition group by clause;

select   count(b1)  from tab1 where condition group by clause;

exit

EOF

uuencode abc.csv abc.csv | mailx -s "Output" email@id.com
```

output

```
           a  b   c

d 

e


result q1

{a1

b1

c1}

result q2

{

A

B

C

}
```

Desired output

```
      a  b  c

d     a1 b1 c1

e     A   B   C
```

how do i get the desired output
and what needs to be done if i have to add a 'total' column after 'c' (column header)

Comment: `sqlplus` is oracle. Are you sure you work with mysql as your question is tagged?

Comment: its #oracle
it was my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a lot, I found `SET COLSEP ","` was giving problem.

So what I did is, I replaced whole script to:

```
sqlplus -s scott/tiger@host<< EOF >/dev/null

SET HEAD OFF FEEDBACK OFF

SET LINES 100

SET PAGES 0

spool abc.csv

select  a||','||b||','|| count(a1)  from tab1 where condition group by clause;

spool off

EOF
```